# what is the SQL query to display names of customers that share same address #dvdrentals

Tags: mysql

I am trying to write a query that will display the customer names that share the same address(e.g husband and wife) in a dvdrental database

This is my query which returned an error message

```
SELECT c.first_name,c.last_name, a.address
COUNT(a.address_id) as count_address
FROM customer as c
JOIN address as a on c.address_id= a.address_id
GROUP by 1,2,3
HAVING COUNT(a.address_id)>1
```

Comment: If you get an error message, share it please.

Comment: Please add a more detailed explanation of what you are trying to achieve, the relevant DDL and the EXPLAIN output for your query. An example with a small sample of data and the expected result would help explain

Answer (score 0):

Your `group by` clause has wrong entities. You only need to group by the address, not the first/last name, as you want to find names and addresses based on address_id which apprears more than once in the customer table.

To achieve the goal we can use a two-step approach in which step 1 will be used as a subquery for the main query in step 2. 
**Step 1:**
We retrieve the address_id which appears more than once in the customer table.

```
select address_id  
from customer
group by address_id
having count(address_id)>1;
```

**Step 2:**
Get the customer names and their corresponding address whose address_id matches the result from the previous query.

```
select first_name,last_name,address
from customer c
join address a
using(address_id)
where c.address_id in (select address_id 
                    from customer
                    group by address_id
                    having count(address_id)>1)
;
```